# Angular ngRoute custom routing based on query parameter

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I'm using the ngRoute in an angular app and was curious if I could extend it for some custom routing.

For example, I'd like to read certain query strings in the URL to do the routing. If the URL ends with something like "index.html?Contacts" I'd like to route this to my contacts template.

```
$routeProvider
        .when('index.html?Home', {
            templateUrl: 'app/home/index.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .when('index.html?Contacts', {
            templateUrl: 'app/contacts/index.html',
            controller: 'ContactsController'
        })
        .when('index.html?About', {
            templateUrl: 'app/about/index.html',
            controller: 'AboutController'
        })
```

As shown above, I'd like to also keep the "index.html" in the URL. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the $routeProvider documentation, you understand that the routeProvider have two parameters

```
when(path, route);
```

Path and route.

Here the Path is not the actual index.html page instead its a virtual path that you want to show in browser when a particular page is hit.

so you can always do something like this

```
$routeProvider
        .when('index/Home', {
            templateUrl: 'app/home/index.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .when('index/Contacts', {
            templateUrl: 'app/contacts/index.html',
            controller: 'ContactsController'
        })
        .when('index/About', {
            templateUrl: 'app/about/index.html',
            controller: 'AboutController'
        })
```